# Docker + TTY CRLF Behavior

Tags: docker, newline, tty

There's a known issue/behavior around `docker run -t`

- `stdout` `stderr` streams both go to `stdout`
- `LF`(`\n`) replaced -> `CRLF` (`\r\n`)

There're explanation in the net that `CRLF` replacements is the matter of an allocated tty it self.

With this in mind

There's an app that under the hood wraps calls to `docker run -t` bypassing `stdio` completely as is.  It runs it own logs under `stderr` and `LF` driven

As a result (combination of docker `stdout:CRLF` and logs `stderr:LF`) the output in the terminal differs depending on another option `docker run -I`
For `docker run -t` it is

```
[err] regular app logs LF
[err] regular app logs LF
[out] docker related outputs CRLF
[out] docker related outputs CRLF
[err] regular app logs LF
[err] regular app logs LF
```

But for  `docker run -it` the terminal output starts being displayed corrupted just after the first CRLF occurrence (yet in byte representation content looks very similar for `run -t` outputs)

```
[err] regular app logs LF
[err] regular app logs LF
[out] docker related outputs CRLF
[out] docker related outputs CRLF
[err] regular app logs LF
[err]                    regular app logs LF
[err]                                       regular app logs LF
```

It looks like terminal automatically switches to `CRLF` mode ofter the first appearance and for the `LF` simply changes the line without turn the carriage back.

So what is not clear

- Actually for what reason the `docker` (it looks like) glues `stdout+stderr`
- Once `CRLF` replacement is the matter of terminal it self why doesn't it do this in consistent way both for `stdout` and `stderr` as well
- Why for (seems to be) similar output content on a same terminal the view of logs differs for `-t` and `-it` runs (the commands actually don't rely in `stdin` at all)

And for the following it maybe should to be asked in a standalone question but mainly this is more about are these related to the root problem cause at all

- At least would it be proper to turn `CRLF` behavior for the terminal (it is macOS)
- in `iterm` I didn't find `CRLF` related option neither on `Text` nor `Terminal` section
- How `stty` and `iterm` settings relate each other

Thanks